# How to export MagicaVoxel to vector?

Tags: vector, export, file-format, magicavoxel

[MagicaVoxel](http://ephtracy.github.io/index.html?page=mv_main) is “a free lightweight 8-bit voxel editor and interactive path tracing renderer”.

It exports to .vox, .slab, .xraw, .qb, .cbj, .ply, .mc, .2d, .iso

I’m not that familiar with these filetypes but I would like to be able to export my MagicaVoxel creations into Illustrator or similar. What workflow would I need for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably an easier way than this, but I have done this and it makes an acceptable vector model:

1. MagicaVoxel —-> Export to .obj
2. Blender —-> Export to .dae
3. SketchUp —-> Export to .pdf

Comment: Why not do it in [blender directly](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/export_svg.html)

Comment: Can blender export to pdf?

Comment: No but it can export svg which can be opened in a vector editor because thats allready vector data. it saves you one step in the workflow and one source of errors. Making it do PDF in the same manner wouldnt be a big deal (a day of work). Though but not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

**None** of the export formats are actually vector formats.

The best you can do, if you want to go straight to Illustrator is export a PNG and place that into Illustrator.

If you want more control, you could export to .obj and open the .obj file with Photoshop. There you can alter rotation, lighting, etc - standard 3D stuff. But again, it's *not* vector. So even if you alter things in Photoshop, the best you could do is *place* the raster image into Illustrator.

Many 3D application actually render as raster and few save/export to vector format. MagicaVoxel appears to be merely a quick polygon-only 3D renderer.